# saving json data in core data iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, core-data

I have a json object which looks like this. This is the fetched json api   from url and i am trying to save it in core data.

```
{"moods_name":"mood1",
"description":"mood",
"c1":"9BFF80",
"c2":"EA8CFF",
"c3"    :"D1FFB0",
"c4":"FF63FC","c5":"6B6B6B",
"font_name":"Default",
"font_size":"3",
"font_color":"000000"}
```

How to store this string by string, or is there another method to store it. please help me.

this is the method where i fetch json array.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSError * localError=nil;
    NSArray *listArray = [NSJSONSerialization  JSONObjectWithData:getData options:0 error:&localError];
    if (!listArray) {
       NSLog(@"error parsing json %@",localError);
    }
    else{
       NSLog(@" JSON DATA%@",listArray);
   }
}
```

my question is how to write the save method to save json array in core data.

Comment: what is the array name, how to json value change, can you please update the code

Comment: i have updated the code. please check it

Comment: ok i will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add all the methods using core data and refer it below,

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Core_Data_Tutorial

if you use all the methods from `AppDelegate` then the ViewController add below two methods

If you get the listArray value, then use the below code,

ViewController Method:

```
   - (IBAction)savevalues:(id)sender {
         // first convert the json array to NSString type code below,

         NSString *m_name = [listArray valueForKey:@"moods_name"];
         NSString *desc = [listArray valueForKey:@"description"];
         NSString *c1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray valueForKey:@"c1"]];
         NSString *c2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray valueForKey:@"c2"]];
         NSString *c3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray valueForKey:@"c3"]];
         NSString *c4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray valueForKey:@"c4"]];
         NSString *font_name = [listArray valueForKey:@"font_name"];
         NSString *font_size = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray valueForKey:@"font_size"]];
         NSString *font_color = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray valueForKey:@"font_color"]];

         [self createNewListWithTitle:m_name describtion:desc c1Val:c1 c2Val:c2 c3Val:c3 c4Val:c4 font_nameVal:font_name font_sizeVal:font_size font_colorVal:font_color];
    }
```

// Upload is NSManagedObject class,

```
- (BOOL) createNewListWithTitle:(NSString *)paramTitle describtion:(NSString *)paramDesc c1Val:(NSString *)paramC1 c2Val:(NSString *)paramC2 c3Val:(NSString *)paramC3 c4Val:(NSString *)paramC4 font_nameVal:(NSString *)paramfont_name font_sizeVal:(NSString *)paramfont_size font_colorVal:(NSString *)paramfont_color {

    BOOL success = NO;
    if ([paramTitle length] == 0){
        NSLog(@"Title is mandatory.");
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"List Not Created" message:@"Please Enter the Keyword, Choose Color" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];

        return NO;
    }

    Upload *newList = [NSEntityDescription
                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Upload"
                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    if (newList == nil){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create the new List");

        return NO;
    }



    newList.name = paramTitle;

    newList.desc =paramDesc;

    newList.c1 =paramC1;

    newList.c2 =paramC2;

    newList.c3 =paramC3;

    newList.c4 =paramC4;


    newList.fontName=paramfont_name;

    newList.fontSize=paramfont_size;

    newList.fontColor=paramfont_color; 

    NSError *savingError = nil;

    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError]){
        NSLog(@"New List was created");
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save the new List, Error = %@", savingError);
    }

    return success;
}
```

don't forgot `#import "Upload.h"` and use the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```

finally call the above Bool method, its save the core data value.

Comment: but there is one problem. i have already created a project and i have not used core data in it. (i have not checked the core data column while creating project) what to do?

Comment: see the link and change the upload class variable name

Comment: No problem manully add the core data, select your projectName -> File -> New -> select Core Data -> select Data Model, next to create the core data

Comment: one more thing, how many attributes do i create in core data model? should it be equal to number of objects in json array?

Comment: its your project how many objects you need, you will create and edit the variable in code

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site it will helpful for you.

http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/